# To change Date Format to "YYYYMMDD"

Tags: c#, .net

I have `DateTime` which contains standard Date Time. I am trying to convert this into `"yyyymmdd"` format.

```
DateTime deliveryDate = myRepository.DeliveryDate; //3/31/2018 12:00:00 AM;
DateTime myDeliveryDate = DateTime.ParseExact(deliveryDate.ToString(),
                                          "yyyymmdd",
                                          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                          DateTimeStyles.None)
```

What is wrong in the above code, I got an error like this:

`String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.at System.DateTimeParse.ParseExact(String s, String format, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles style)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DateTime` class doesn't store the date in a particular format, if you want it represented like *yyyymmdd* you have to convert it to a `string`:

```
string myDeliveryDate = deliveryDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

You should note that month is a capital M (small m is for minutes).

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime` is just the container of all the information. If you want it parsed in `yyyyMMdd` format, use

```
string myDeliveryDate = deliveryDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```